# Image in pygame is moving diagonally instead of left,right, up and down

Tags: pygame

Im just trying to get an image to move left, right, up and down in pygame using WASD. It works fine if I start with moving only left to right or only up and down. But when i change from moving left-right to moving up or down (or the other way around) the image starts to move diagonally instead. Anyone know why?

Im using python 3.3.0. Pygame 1.9.2

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()

screen=pygame.display.set_mode((640,480))
image = pygame.image.load('Player.png')

x,y=0,0
movex, movey=0,0

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        if event.type==KEYDOWN:
            if event.key==K_d:
                movex=+10
            elif event.key==K_a:
                movex=-10
            elif event.key==K_s:
                movey=+10
            elif event.key==K_w:
                movey=-10

            x+=movex
            y+=movey
screen.fill((200, 200, 200))
screen.blit(image, ( x,y))
pygame.display.flip()
```

Answer (score 0):

You should reset the sprite's velocity within the loop. Move `movex` and `movey` down a bit.

```
x,y=0,0

while True:
    movex, movey=0,0
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        if event.type==KEYDOWN:
            if event.key==K_d:
                movex=+10
            elif event.key==K_a:
                movex=-10
            elif event.key==K_s:
                movey=+10
            elif event.key==K_w:
                movey=-10

            x+=movex
            y+=movey
```

Now, when you release A and press W, it will move up instead of diagonally.

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right path but overlooked one thing. If I press the right key, movex = 10 right? Well if I then press the up key, movey = 10 but movex = 10 still since you didn't get rid of it change its value. So in your up and down blocks (if/elif/else) make sure to say

```
Movex = 0
```

And in your left and right blocks

```
Movey = 0
```

And I bet you will keep moving after you let go of the button too right? To fix that, copy the KEYDOWN block with all of your controls, and change KEYDOWN to KEYUP. Then in all of your letter blocks like: `if event.key == K_a`, `if it is w or s` get rid of the code in it and add

```
Movey = 0
```

And the opposite for a and d:

```
Movex = 0
```

Hope this helps!